# How do I embed a simple static webpage in a blackberry app?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, webview

I have an app that I'm developing and the main screen is supposed to have a simple embedded browser frame on it that displays a single remote webpage. Can anyone provide me with the necessary code or a reference that will help me figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what OS version you are going to support. Since OS 5.0 RIM adds a new package `net.rim.device.api.browser.field2` which simplifies things a lot. For both old API (pre 5) and newer there is a sample apps in the BB SDK that demonstrates embedded browser usage.

On my PC sample apps are in the following dirs:

- C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0\samples\com\rim\samples\device\browser\browserfield2demo - newer API
- C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0\samples\com\rim\samples\device\browser\browserfielddemo - old API

Also note that the sample for old API actually fails to open an HttpConnection. It results in white screen being displayed instead of page content, so feel free to fix the sample code to append the URL with a proper suffix (`;device=true` or `;interface=wifi`). I assume you already know how to open HttpConnection on BB using different transports.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using the Eclipse plugin and can't seem to find the samples directory. Is it included with the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: @Ghost1227: I don't use Eclipse plugin, so I just don't know. I'm sure you could use search for files by "import net.rim.device.api.browser.field" string inclusion on your file system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes can you please try this.

```
  BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
  browserSession.displayPage("http://www.google.co");
  browserSession.showBrowser();
```